# Automatically no-overwrite in ssh-keygen

Tags: bash, ssh-keygen

If I run

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa`

and the file `id_rsa` already exists, it will prompt me whether I want to overwrite:

```
id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?
```

How do I automatically answer no in a bash script? I checked `man ssh-keygen` but couldn't find any such option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could simply do like this:
echo "n"|ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa

Answer (score 2):

You can use [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) to automatically answer `n` to the `Overwrite (y/n)?` question.

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f id_rsa <<< n
```